# scala inheritance and lower bound issue

Tags: scala, lower-bound

I'm having some issues with inheritance and lower bounds in scala; I'll try to explain it with an example:
I have a class Person with a signature like:

```
def doSomething[P<%Person](persons :List[P]) {
}
```

I've also created a child class Worker, and his method doSomething looks like this:

```
override def doSomething(persons: List[Worker]) {
}
```

However this fires an error, stating that Worker.doSomething() doesn't override anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot inherit this way. It violates the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). I'll show why that is the case. Suppose you could compile these classes:

```
class Person {
    def doSomething[P<%Person](persons :List[P]) {
    }
}

class Worker extends Person {
    override def doSomething(persons: List[Worker]) {
    }
}
```

Now, this simple program would fail:

```
val p1: Person = new Worker
val p2: Person = new Person
p1.doSomething(List(p2))
```

Since `p2` is not a `Worker`, that call is invalid. However, since `p1` is a `Person`, that call is valid! This contradiction is a result of the override you propose.

But it's worse than that! This ALSO won't work:

```
p1.doSomething[Worker](List(p1))
```

Now, even though it is passing a list of workers, as expected by `p1`, it fails because `doSomething` in `Worker` *doesn't expect a type parameter*. However, the method `doSomething` of `Person` declared that a type parameter should be passed! Again, the contradiction is a result of the override you propose.

Remember that inheritance is a *is-a* kind of relationship. If `Worker` is a `Person`, then it should *act* like a `Person` in all ways one expects a `Person` to act. If that's not the kind of relationship you want to create, then do not use inheritance.

Answer (score 4):

A specific method cannot override a generic method (though a specific class can extend a generic class) because the generic method says it will work as long as you pass it *any* subclass of person.  The specific method will not take *any* subclass; it will only take `Worker`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however in the Worker.doSomething() method I'd like to access attributes of the Worker class (which are not in generic Person class). Is there a way to access these properties (without casting)?

Comment: @user485659 - Can you describe a bit more of what you're trying to do?  As my answer highlights, overriding the class is logically incorrect; casting would also be (logically, if not practically) incorrect, since the cast might fail (i.e. that method has no guarantee to be called only with List[Worker] as arguments in generic code that works with Persons).

Comment: @user485659 If you have another question, ask it in another question. But, briefly, you should never ask something of an object; instead you should tell it what to do, in which case it takes care of the mechanics itself. You can use _pattern matching_, however, to avoid keeping to good practices.